# How to make store keys accessible just like any other attribute of the model when rendering as JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, store, accessor

I have a settings column(jsonb datatype) in users table, which I would like to deserialize and make it accessible to the model. Here is how my model looks like.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  store_accessor :settings, :color, :locale
end
```

`User.first.color` works

But `User.first.as_json` does not include `color` key at row level, it is available inside `settings`.

Similarly `render json: User.find(params[:id])` does the same thing.

How can I make `color` and `locale` available at row level when rendering JSON?

Comment: there are many ways, I'd recommend using https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers so that you have full control of what you're serializing and don't mess up things by overriding the `as_json` method in your `User` model.

Answer (score 0):

`User.first.as_json` or `render json: User.find(params[:id])` won't get your desired result. The same happens when you wish to construct a json having an attribute which is returned from a model function.

I use Jbuilder (https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) to serialize. It works great for rendering json.

Example code,

### users_controller.rb

```
def function_x 
    @user = User.first
end
```

### /views/function_x.json.jbuilder

```
json.extract! @user, :id, :other_params_from_users_table
json.color @user.color
json.locale @user.locale
```

Now your json should look something like this,

```
{
    id: ....,
    param1: value 1,
    param2: value 2,
    color: color_value,
    locale: locale_value
}
```

Comment: I have STI setup, where store_accessor is defined for all the child classes. I don't like the fact that I would have to define jbuilder for all the controllers. The information to unnest the store at row level is available in `store_accessor` and should be easily usable just like `render json: User.first, include: [:roles]` (User has_many roles)

Comment: @Mo3z I know it has been years, but did you ever find a suitable solution to this?